# Contact Detail page launched from url

Tags: visualforce

I want to launch Contact detail page without a sidebar from a visualforce page.

The code looks like this:

```
window.open('/' + contact_id);
```

I thought I might be able to add a url parameter:

```
window.open('/' + contact_id+'/?sidebar=false');
```

it didn't work. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render the page without the sidebar you will need to use a custom visualforce page. This would be a very simple page:

Per this help doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_detail.htm

```
<!-- For this example to render properly, you must associate the Visualforce page 
with a valid account record in the URL. 
For example, if 001D000000IRt53 is the account ID, the resulting URL should be: 
https://Salesforce_instance/apex/myPage?id=001D000000IRt53
See the Visualforce Developer's Guide Quick Start Tutorial for more information. -->

<apex:page standardController="Contact">
   <apex:detail subject="{!contact.ownerId}" relatedList="false" title="false"/> 
</apex:page>
```

So for your usage, create a visualforce page like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" sidebar="false">
       <apex:detail subject="{!contact.ownerId}" relatedList="true" title="false"/> 
</apex:page>
```

and direct your code to this url (assuming you named the page `myvf`)

`window.open('/apex/myvf?id=' + contact_id)`

Comment: Am I missing something? I need to do this for a Contact page, not an account.

When I try to add sidebar="false" for Contact vf page it says "sidebar" isn't supported.

Comment: Whoops I swapped the code in my example. Fixing now.

Comment: Still get - "sidebar" isn't supported.

Comment: D'oh, the sidebar parameter needs to be in the `<apex:page>` tag.

Comment: Yeah Doh! I should have caught that one. I'll give it a try and let you know.